# Newsletter subscription confirmation text

Tags: kentico

i have a website in the new Kentico 8. I use a newsletter subscription web part and it works fine. The only problem i have, is the website culture is dutch, but when you subscribe for the newsletter, the confirmation text is in English. I've searched everywhere but i can't find, where i can change the text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried CMS\CMSResources\CMS.resx?